# How to return 2 dimension c++ array to php?

Tags: php, c++, multidimensional-array

I have a C++ program that parses a text file and the result is 2 dimensional array with tokens for each line. The C++ program is called from the php file. How can I return the 2 dimensional C++ array to php?

Comment: what function are you using to exec the C++ program ? 'exec()' ?

Comment: Please submit the code for further reference. Besides, which function are you using? exec allows a parameter $output (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: Yes, I am using the exec() function to execute the C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way to do that, is to dump your c++ array into a file, and after that, your php code can read from it, but you need to modify your c++ code i guess